# Is it possible to dectect if WFS or WMS is disabled in GeoServer CSW extension

Tags: geoserver

I am creating a mapping file for the CSW extension in GeoServer and need to determine if the WMS and WFS services is actually enabled in order to create valid online resources links.

I have followed the Inspire example, but it always creates links to both WMS and WFS/WCS.

The best I have gotten so far is using the *disabledServices* property, but that is a list of strings and I haven't figured out a good way to determine if a list contains a value. There is the *in* and *inN*-operators, but they take values as arguments not a list. I could take out the values from the list using *litem* as there are at most three items in the list, but the *in*-operator crashes on for those layers that have no disabled services.

The hack I can use is *concatenate* on the *litem*s of the list and do a *strMatch* to see if the resulting string contains the service. The concatenation can be simplified as *concatenate(disabledServies)* as it will use java's default toString on the list and make a comma sparated string. But somehow I think there is a better way, but I cannot find any documentation which functions and properties are actually available to the CSW mapping file.